# how do I insert from NEW or OLD into a dynamically named table within a PostgreSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have a number of tables with associated audit tables. The tables are named respectively X and X_aud where X is the name of the table to be audited. I have a trigger function that I call before INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE and I want to call the same function for all my tables but I can't figure out how to write my trigger function. What I've tried so far is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_maintenance() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_aud VALUES ' || OLD.*;
   RETURN OLD;
END IF;

EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_aud VALUES ' || NEW.*;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And various other versions with the NEW.* inside the quotes etc. But nothing seems to work. Has anyone else tried something similar and if so how did you do it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of a couple of audit triggers available on the postgresql wiki.

[pre 9.1](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger)

[9.1 or above](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus)

Comment: Thanks Gary but I couldn't see any use there of one trigger function applying auditing to multiple tables. The problem I've got is with the syntax to generate a statement that can update a table whose name is generated from the name of the table being changed and simultaneously reference the NEW and OLD values

Answer (score 0):

the question has already been asked (and nicely answered). The solution is to use the EXECUTE ... USING syntax. This certainly works in 9.3 but the original answer said that it worked in 8.4 and above

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_aud SELECT $1.*' USING NEW;
```